# Invalid Access to FAT (entry 0x0606bfdf)

Tags: installation, usb, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 over a corrupted partition of Windows 7. Booting from USB I select Install on HDD and everything is fine and dandy until i get this error half way though initial load right after splash screen.

> [     10.733813] FAT-fs (sdb): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x0606bfdf)

I have formatted my USB as A FAT 32 device before booting from it. Also have tried to install with in windows. Keeping windows intact but get another error message about missing files. And also tried to install from CD nothing is working. What would be the next step (easiest) Should I just completely erase HDD before placing Ubuntu on?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.